# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un sumatorio en matlab?

Tags: matlab, octave

Me gustaría saber cómo se hace en matlab un sumatorio.

Tenemos un vector 'v' de 10 valores.

El sumatorio va desde 0 hasta 10.

Dentro del cuerpo del sumatorio tenemos un 10^(v). Aquí tengo que acceder a cada valor del vector v.

También me gustaría representar cada valor del sumatorio.

Lo que ya tengo es:

```
nm = 10; %limite superior
v= [99.1, 98.4, 104, 104, 98.3, 98.3, 102, 99.5, 99.4, 98.7] %vector

%sumatorio
for i=1:nm
    s=10^(v(i));
end

resultado = 10*log((1/nm)*s);
```

Comment: Que has intentado? Muestra tu código. Así podremos ayudarte

Comment: Coloca v[i], así accedes al valor del vector o Matriz

Comment: al declarar el vector?

Comment: No,en la operación s=10^(v[i])

Answer (score 1):

Matlab al igual que otros lenguajes de cálculo ya ofrece operaciones que simplifican mucha sintaxis de código, en este caso se requiere sumar 10 elevado a la potencia de cada elemento contenido en el vector `v`.

Como no se trata de operaciones con matrices -*el algebra lineal 
es lo fuerte de Matlab*- sino empleado un vector, se requiere usar el operador `.`

```
s = sum(10.^v)
```

Con lo cual el resultado sería

```
r = 10*log((1/nm)*s)
r;  % imprimimos resultado
```

Solo acotar que `nm` también se pudo obtener con `nm = length(v)`

Para aprovechar las bondades de Matlab mi recomendación es que se revise álgebra lineal también.

**CONSIDERACIONES**

Una opción -*open source*- similar a Matlab, es [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), siendo su  sintaxis la misma que de Matlab, por tanto la solución antes expuesta también es válida para dicho programa.